# How to render text only data inserted from WYSIWYG editor?

Tags: laravel

I am using admin lte summer note. There is a image upload option as well. I have uploaded a image at the very beginning of the blog. But in landing page where i have to show blog (image, title, and little bit of description) in description part it renders image but i want to render text only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation is to add new field to the blog database and name it prefix where you put small description about your blog, anyhow you can skip html tags by using this helper

```
{{ strip_tags($yourString) }}
```

but yet the prefix field method is better